# mysql - get the date of the latest acceptable gap

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I'm struggling with the following scenarios to extract the datetime.

If there are no 12 months or more interval, it should return null (see id 2).

If there exist 2 or more 12 months gaps the latest gap should be considered (see id 1)

If there is only one gap then that should be considered (see id 3)

```
id | datetime
1  | 2018-01-01
1  | 2018-01-02
1  | 2019-02-01
1  | 2019-02-02
1  | 2020-03-01
1  | 2020-03-02
2  | 2018-01-01
2  | 2018-01-02
3  | 2018-01-01
3  | 2018-01-02
3  | 2019-02-01
```

Expected result should be,

```
id | datetime
1  | 2020-03-01
2  | null
3  | 2019-02-01
```

The result is grouped by the id. For id 1, 2020-03-01 is selected because it is the closest to the last 12 or more months gap that exists within the id 1. (1st gap is 2019-02-01 - 2018-01-02 >= 12, 2nd gap is 2020-03-01 - 2019-02-02 The 2020-03-01 is selected since it is the height value of the last acceptable gap)

Although I tried grouping with id it is not possible to loop and see how many gaps are there and then select the latest gap.

In postgres I hope we can use a lag() function with a window function, so that I can order the datetime and deduct the two adjacent datetimes, which can be used as a subquery and get the maximum out of all the results.
 But I want to do this in mysql.

```
lag("datetime") over (order by "datetime") - "datetime" as diff,
```

Comment: the only think is a stored procedure where you loop through all rows and check for TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,mindate,maxdate) and id change

Comment: Well, one option is to upgrade

Comment: I found a solution posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution using MySql variables,

```
SELECT
    data.id,
    MAX(data.eligible_datetime)
FROM (
    SELECT
        z.id,
        z.datetime,
        IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, @prevDate, z.datetime) > 11 AND @prevID = z.id, z.datetime, NULL) eligible_datetime,
        @prevDate := z.datetime,
        @prevID := z.id
    FROM tablename z,
    (
        SELECT
            @prevID := NULL,
            @prevDate := NULL
    ) vars
    ORDER BY z.id, z.datetime
) data
GROUP BY data.id
```